# Regex floating point Number Formatter for Wpf Textbox

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, floating-point, formatter

I saw Regex today for the first time. I need a regex formatter for my WPF Textbox like this:
12345,1234
I need a decimal separator like "," or "." and negative Numbers should be allowed.
So you can write something like this:

230,56 / 1289,4 / -1.9 / 63478,1252 / 0.3265

This should not be possible:

086,344 / 34,7000 / 1.0×10−4

A 0 at first if there is not a comma behind there should not be allowed. And if the last Number after the Comma is a 0 is also bad. No scientific notation.

I found a code for simple integer values:

```
private void Int_PreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            // Just Ints
            Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
            e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
        }
```

So how does a formatter for floating point numbers like my description looks like?

Comment: Is the comma mandatory or is also "1" allowed? Is "1,0" allowed? Is a minus sign allowed? What about scientific notation?

Comment: So why is `23,560` allowed when you state *"And if the last Number after the Comma is a 0 is also bad."*

Comment: Sorry. You're right. 
I need a decimal separator like "," or ".".
Negative Number should be allowed.
No scientific notation.

Sorry I should be more specific with my questions.

Comment: Why don't you bind the `Text` of your `TextBox` to a `double`or a `float`? In that case, WPF will make sure that the user entered a valid input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your requirements, it seems that the following pattern would work:

```
^-?(?!.*0$)(?!0\d)\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uAJKsI/3)

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `-?` - Optional hyphen to allow for negative values.
- `(?!.*0)` - Negative lookahead to prevent a string that ends with `0`.
- `(?!0\d)` - Negative lookahead to prevent a string that starts with `0` and a digit.
- `\d+` - Any digit at least once.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group.

  - `[,.]` - A comma or dot as decimal delimiter.
  - `\d+` - One or more digits.
  - `)?` - Close non-capture group and make it optional.
- `$` - End string ancor.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your requirements as follows:

- The string might have an optional "-" character in front
- Before the decimal separator, there should be either a single "0", or any number of digits not starting with a "0".
- After the decimal separator, there should be either a single "0", or any number of digits not ending with a "0".

This translates straightforward to the following regex:

```
@"^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)[,\.](0|\d*[1-9])$"
```

If numbers without decimal separators are allowed (the question is not clear about this), the part starting from the separator would be optional, i.e.

```
@"^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)([,\.](0|\d*[1-9]))?$"
```

Comment: @Peregrine the question is not clear about whether this should be allowed ot not

Comment: Added a variant matching numbers without decimal separator

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if user entered valid decimal number, .NET offers you readable and simple way of validating that. Justs use `decimal.TryParse`

In the spirit of "use the right tool for the job", you should not use regex for such validation.

Just use it like:

```
var parseOk = decimal.TryParse(textBlock.Text, out _); // here I used _ as parameter name, as it is not relevant
if(! parseOk)
{
    // validation failed
}
```

In order to control how decimal separators are treated, you can use overload fo metnioned method:

```
public static bool TryParse (string s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style,
    IFormatProvider provider, out decimal result);
```

And please look at [the docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Decimal__)

Also, you have to decide how number will be stored (float, decimal or double). Fortunately, each of these types exposes two static methods: `Parse` and `TryParse` - I encourage you to read about them.

Comment: While I would do it the same way, it does not fulfill the specific requirements in the question.